# How do I get a column value where the condition spans over two rows?

Tags: sql

I have a table with the current values:

[image: Result of two queries]

What I want is to get the `projekt` value where kod is `Greger` and `Åutte`.

As of now, my attempt returns nothing. Since the condition spans over two rows, I have no idea how to get the `projekt` I need.

The wanted result would look like this:

[image]

I might be a little rude asking for magic here but i'm currently out of magic points.

How do I get a column value where the condition spans over two rows?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly then You can use **In clause**. like this - `select 
projekt 
from myTable 
where kod in ('Greger','Åutte')`

Comment: Why the downvote, I think this is a proper question and is not specific nor broad.

Comment: By the answers you have received, I think the downvot may be because it is not very clear the exact result set you want. Add that you want only projekts that have both kod values, albeit on different rows... or add the expected result set. That will make the question better ;)

Comment: @Frazz Thanks for the pointers. I'll update my question body to better reflect the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT a.projekt
FROM myTable a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT b.projekt
  FROM myTable b
  WHERE b.projekt=a.projekt AND kod='Greger'
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT c.projekt
  FROM myTable c
  WHERE c.projekt=a.projekt AND kod='Åutte'
)
```

Another way is to COUNT the matching records, but you have to be sure you count DISTINCT kod values:

```
SELECT projekt
FROM myTable
WHERE kod IN ('Greger','Åutte')
GROUP BY projekt
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kod)=2
```

This can be simplified if you know that (projekt, kod) is a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key of myTable:

```
SELECT projekt
FROM myTable
WHERE kod IN ('Greger','Åutte')
GROUP BY projekt
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

**In all cases, best ensure you have an index on (projekt, kod) if this table is big ;)**

Comment: Thanks, this was kind of what i was looking for. Yours and Alex answer both works.

Comment: Yes. Just beware that the COUNT can be tricky. It's results in this case depend a bit on if (projekt, kod) is UNIQUE or not. Just beware of **what** you count. The EXISTS is a bit more readable and solid, but it may be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about something similar?

```
select 
distinct projekt 
from myTable 
where kod in ('Greger','Åutte')
group by projekt
having count(projekt) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the statement to

```
Select * from myTable where kod = 'Greger' OR kod = 'Åutte'
```

or with in

```
Select * from myTable where kod in ('Greger', 'Åutte')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE kod = 'Greger' OR kod='Autte'
```

Your actual statement ask for a row where kod is Greger and autte for each row, wich is impossible as there is only One kod column.

If you consider more tan two condition for one column. The IN clause suggested in other answer could be a good solution, as it reduces a lot verbosity of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

use `in`

```
select projekt from myTable where kod in ('Greger','Åutte');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use OR which will allow the selection if one of this two condition available :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHEREkod = 'GREGER' OR kod='AUTTE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using SQL Server, so you can use the `intersect` keyword like so:

```
select * from tbl where projekt in
(select projekt from tbl where kod = 'Greger'
 intersect
 select projekt from tbl where kod = 'Åutte')
```

`Intersect` will return all projects which have rows for both the entries. You can then select all the columns from your table based on the result of the subquery.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PPBIO16659)

Answer (score 0):

there is more than one possibility

```
SELECT DISTINCT projekt FROM users
WHERE kod IN('Greger','Åutte')
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT projekt FROM users 
WHERE kod = 'Greger' OR kod = 'Åutte'
```